# C# I can't inherit from another project not recognizing namespace - error could not find namespace

Tags: c#, visual-studio

If anyone could point me in the right direction not understanding why I see both namespaces in one project and not the other?

[image]

Comment: Missing a reference?

Comment: I'm new, what do you mean a using statement?

Comment: where is the FADTO thing you are trying to use defeined, is it in this project? Show the code where its defined

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/how-to-add-or-remove-references-by-using-the-reference-manager?view=vs-2022

Comment: FADTO was added as an additional project

Answer (score 1):

In the **Solution Explorer** in **Visual Studio**, shown right in your image, right-click on the `Dependencies` node right inside and first in the `FABackEnd` node. In the popup-menu, click on `Add Project Reference...` Then in the `Projects` list, check `FADTO` if it isn't checked already.

In the source shown there are several `using` statements at the top. Below these, add another `using` statement that looks like this.

```
using FADTO;
```

Comment: I got this error "Adding this project as a reference would cause a circular dependency "

Comment: I'm following a tutorial where I started a project FABackend. I had a user class created in FAbackend. I then added the FADTO as a core project they both have the same frame work version. The purpose is to create a data transfer object and define the user class there, which I did. I than begin to get errors as I tried to inherit the user class from FADTO as it can't find the namespace.

Comment: You cannot have circular references between DLLs, meaning they can't use each other, so you have to architect your code in such a way that it doesn't happen. There must be a usage hierarchy that is a tree structure, with the executable as the root. Often in a situation like this, the solution is to create yet another DLL, and move common code into that DLL.

Comment: I was able to resolve the issue by going into FADTO and deleting the project folder from Dependencies. I then added the reference back FABackend